# How to find all the messages of the TXs of an Address?

Tags: pyota

I'd like to find every message attached to the transactions of an address
So I have to search transaction by address with find_transactions(), then list all the signature_message_fragment
How can I do this? I tried this:

`list_add = [Address('MYADDRESS')]
print(api.find_transactions(addresses = list_add))`

and I get all the TXs hashes. Now how can I list all the signature_message_fragment?

Comment: Never used PyOTA, but there should be a GetTrytes or similar function which you pass in transaction hashes and get transaction trytes back. Then wrap that trytes into `TransactionTrytes` objects (or use substring parsing) to get the messages out.

Answer (score 1):

There's a utility function called `find_transaction_objects` ([that will be added to the main API soon](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.py/issues/99)) that may be useful here.

It does the same thing as `find_transactions`, except it then converts the trytes that the IRI sends back into proper `iota.transaction.base.Transaction` objects.

Once you have `Transaction` objects, you can access each one's `signature_message_fragment` (which is an `iota.types.TryteString` object) and `decode` it:

```
from iota.commands.extended.utils import find_transaction_objects

transactions = find_transaction_objects(addresses=list_add)

for transaction in transactions:
  # Ignore input transactions; these have cryptographic signatures,
  # not human-readable messages.
  if transaction.value < 0:
    continue

  print(f'Message from {transaction.hash}:')

  message = transaction.signature_message_fragment
  if message is None:
    print('(None)')
  else:
    print(message.decode())
```